# There is any function in EXCEL which is separate text from number?

Tags: regex, string, excel, function

I mean for example in A1: 123b maybe the best put 123 to B and "b" for C column. Any function for that?

Comment: No, I don't think so. VBA with regex maybe will be able to do this however.

Comment: You would have to create you own VBA-function in case you want to do this.

Comment: You could build a couple formulas using [This site on extraction](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/extracting-numbers-from-alphanumeric-strings-HA001154901.aspx) as a starting reference, swapping out the `ISNUMBER` with other funtions like `ISTEXT` and `ISNONTEXT`, would there ever be cases where the numbers and letters would intermingle? i.e. 12a34b56c?

Comment: no numbers can be 1,2 or 3 digit, letters always after the numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the numbers are always at the beginning, then, for the numbers:

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,--LEFT(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:20"))),LEFT(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:20"))))
```

and for the letters:

```
   =MID(A1,LEN(LOOKUP(9.9E+307,--LEFT(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:20"))),LEFT(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:20")))))+1,20)
```

The "20"'s in the formulas just needs to be some number that is larger than the length of the longest string you might be processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the number part of the value (assumed to be in A1), use the array formula (control-shift-enter after entering the formula):

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"},A1),LEN(A1)))-1))
```

The formula does the following:

- for each letter, find the first index of the character in the string
- if the string is not found, assume the value is the length (not found)
- find the minimum of the indices
- take the substring starting from the first character and ending just before the first letter
- get the numeric value for the text (which should be all-digits at this point)

To get the text part:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)+1-MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"},A1),LEN(A1))))
```